# Android, saving the status of a dynamic UI: SQLite vs Flat File

Tags: android, sqlite, storage

in my app I have a dynamic UI (created through layout inflation) which is mostly made of timers that the user can start and stop.

I already implemented the screen rotation with saveInstanceState() and the bundle stuff.

Now I was wondering how to preserve the UI state when the user willingly leave the app. I have a list of TextViews updated by threads (if the timer is running). So to recreate the status of the UI I have to save the following info: remaining_time (long), started (true of false), order (to place every timer int he correct position)

Since I don't have to make queries or searches, but just go through the whole data and recreate the timers I'd say that a flat file with one line per timer would be better in this situation.

Am I wrong? Should I be using SQLite?

Comment: Why not use SharedPreferences instead? Very easy to implement.

Comment: Well, I thought that needed an ordered list just saving and retrieving one line at the time for the file would it be better.

But you may be right. I could get the size of all the preferences and then getting the values iterating on the keys. And the keys would be ordered int so I could do something like prefs.get(i) for i=0 to prefs.getAll().size()

Comment: Since you have a list of the items you could create a method for the list to put them as a single string that can be broken download into multiple strings, or put one string per key. Both of them would work for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

As @Hiemanshu suggested it si better to store splittable Strings in the SharedPreferences